# What AWS IAM Policy to grant Admin right only on ressources created by your Identity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy

I have an AWS account used by different people.

I want to give access to IAM Users in the *IAM User Group Developer* to only the resources they created. **They should be able to create any resources and read and write all the resources they created**.

So, when you logged as *IAM User A* part of IAM User Group Developer, you can read and edit all the resources *IAM User A* has created since the beginning. Also, you will be able to create any other resources.

I prefer to avoid using AWS Organisations. Moreover, there are resources shared across the account. There is already an Admin role and a ReadOnly role for these resources.

One solution would be to ask developers to use their AWS Accounts and permit them to access the main one with IAM Roles. However, I would like your help with a **solution using only one AWS Account**.

Comment: That is generally not possible. AWS resources do not belong to user entities, they belong to the account.

Comment: Thank you for your answer  A second solution would be to use a tag for resources with the value being the IAM User entity and then give permissions based on this tag. I didn't mention this solution initially because I believe it is more of a trick than a solution.